# Can these Sync Rules be satisfied using just Sync Framework 2.1 & FileSyncProvider

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to satisfy the following requirements using MS Sync Framework 2.1 to sync files between two folders.  It seems to me I may need additional logic other than just Sync Framework.  Seems rule #2 is not doable.

1. files added to local repository are copied up to master repository (can be done)
2. files deleted from local repository will be copied back from the master (this seems like it cannot be done to me using sync framework alone)
3. files deleted from master repository are also deleted from local repository (can be done)
4. files added to the master repository are copied to local repository (can be done)

Thanks for reading and your input.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean for rule#2? You mean: when a file is deleted from local, I want to keep the *master* version? This would be possible using SyncFramework, but I'm affraid you can't restore the *local* version of the file to the *master* repository since the file has been deleted.

Comment: rule#2 being... bullet point #2 in my list of requirements.  Yes that is what I was afraid of.  So as such I'll have to write a routine to do so.  Thanks

Comment: #2 can be achieved by running detect changes on your local repository, determining files that were deleted and copying them over. however, when you do #1, the files you just copied over will appear as new files and will be uploaded so you have to intercept and skip them from uploading.